# Несколько реализаций для одного класса

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Для android существует такая вещь как ProductFlavors. Хочется получиться тоже самое и для простой java и в итоге получить jar'ник.

```
Project
 src
--emul
   package
    ClassA
--main
   package
    ClassA
    ClassB
    ClassC
--mock
   package
    ClassA
```

Но каждый раз когда я компилирую получаю ClassA из папки main. Так же попробовал использовать плагин com.lazan.javaflavours, ситуацию такая же. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема и в какую сторону копать? Если в jar прописать from sourceSets.mock.output или from sourceSets.emul.output то всё получается как надо, но как только я прописываю в конкретный Task то на выходе получаю последнии исходники(какой бы jar не компилировал всегда получаю mock'овский). Код build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        // todo add dependencies
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "com.lazan.javaflavours" version "1.2"
}

group 'CashDesk'
version '1.0.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

javaFlavours {
    flavour 'emul'
    flavour 'mock'
}

sourceSets {

    emul {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/emul/java'
        }
    }

    mock {

        java {
            srcDirs 'src/mock/java'
        }
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Cash desk API',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Built-Date': new Date(),
                'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version'),
                'Built-Gradle': gradle.gradleVersion
    }

    exclude('by/avest/softwarecashdesk/example/**')
}

compileJava {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

task createJarEmulator(type: Jar) {
    baseName = 'cashdesk'

    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }

    with jar
}

task createJarMocks(type: Jar) {
    baseName = 'cashdesk'

    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }

    with jar
}
```